# using an sqlite3 database with an ios8 app using Xcode 6 and swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite, ios8

i'm fairly new to programming.  I am working with Xcode 6 and swift to build an iOS 8 app.  my app has quite lot of data which i have organised into sqlite3 files using the firefox add on.  i have dropped these files into my project folder.  their extension is .sql   now i need to access that data in my app.  i have already linked the sqlite3 library by adding libsqlite3.dylib in the build phases tab.  now i want to write the code to access the database.  i have found a lot of information online with code and examples from iOS 7 and earlier using objective-c but nothing with iOS 8 and swift.  if anybody can help me or lead me in the right direction i would be grateful.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sqlite.swift framework to implement database connection with swift
here is link https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md

Here is example to connect sqlite database

```
 var db : Database!
var cat = Expression<String>("ZCATEGORY")
var name = Expression<String>("ZNAME")
var user : Query!
var stmt : Query!
var data : Array<Row>!

@IBOutlet var tabe: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    createdb()
}



 internal func createdb()
{
  // bundle database  within your app
  let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("db", ofType: "sqlite")
    println(path)
    db = Database(path, readonly: true)
    // ZFOOD is table name
    user = db["ZFOOD"]
    println(db)
    // select distinct(cat) from ZFOOD
    stmt = user.select(distinct : cat)
    // Stored query result in array
     data = Array(stmt)

   }

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell: AnyObject = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
     cell.textLabel.text = data[indexPath.row][cat]
    return cell as UITableViewCell
}
```

I hope this helpful for you

Comment: hi. thanks for your reply. i was really trying to just call the sql library myself without using any wrapper. i've looked at other posts doing that but they all seem to create the table and input values. i already have a database which i don't want to modify. i just want to access values from the table. for example, the table has two columns. i just want to treat the first column as a key and second column as the value. I've been on this for a very long time with no luck...

Comment: if you use sqlite.swift wrapper then i will help you because i never used sql library

Comment: hi.  thanks for the updated code.  i get use of undeclared identifier for Database which is the type of your db variable.  where does this type come from?  thanks

Comment: oh, sorry.  I think you are using the sqlite.swift wrapper.  i was hoping to achieve this without a wrapper.  thx

Comment: if you want any other help i will do my best to help you